# How do I parse the results of a querySelectorAll selector engine & allow method chaining?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

SIMPLIFIED EXAMPLE CODE:

```
var $ = function(selector, node) { // Selector engine
    var selector = selector.trim(), node = node || document.body;
    if (selector != null) {
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(node.querySelectorAll(selector), 0); }
    }
}
```

I want to use it like this...:

```
$("div").innerHTML='It works!';
```

...not like this...:

```
$("div")[0].innerHTML='It works only on the specified index!';
```

...or this:

```
for(i=0;i<$('div');i++) {
        $("div")[i].innerHTML='It works great but it's ugly!';
}
```

This is as close as I got. I would like chaining to work and for it to be compatible with native methods:

```
if(!Array.prototype.innerHTML) { 
    Array.prototype.innerHTML = function(html) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            this[i].innerHTML = html;
        }
    }
}

$("div").innerHTML('It works, but it ruins method chaining!');
```

I decided to build this engine to better learn JavaScript; It's working but I am hoping I can learn some more from the kind members of Stack Overflow. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'd review some of the relevant libraries and frameworks `.html()` and `.text()` source code for how they do it, ones like jQuery, MooTools, Prototype, YUI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to use it like this...:
>
> ```
> $("div").innerHTML='It works!';
> ```
>
> ...not like this...:
>
> ```
> $("div")[0].innerHTML='It works only on the specified index!';
> ```

It sounds like you want to have assigning to `innerHTML` on your set of results assign to the `innerHTML` of *all* of the results.

To do that, you'll have to use a function, either directly or indirectly.

Directly:

```
var $ = function(selector, node) { // Selector engine
    var selector = selector.trim(),
        node = node || document.body,
        rv;
    if (selector != null) {
        rv = Array.prototype.slice.call(node.querySelectorAll(selector), 0); }
        rv.setInnerHTML = setInnerHTML;
    }
    return rv;
}
function setInnerHTML(html) {
    var index;

    for (index = 0; index < this.length; ++index) {
        this[index].innerHTML = html;
    }
}

// Usage
$("div").setInnerHTML("The new HTML");
```

There, we define a function, and we assign it to the array you're returning as a property. You can then call that function on the array. (You might want to use `Object.defineProperty` if it's available to set the `setInnerHTML` property, so you can make it non-enumerable.)

Indirectly (requires an ES5-enabled JavaScript engine):

```
var $ = function(selector, node) { // Selector engine
    var selector = selector.trim(),
        node = node || document.body,
        rv;
    if (selector != null) {
        rv = Array.prototype.slice.call(node.querySelectorAll(selector), 0); }
        Object.defineProperty(rv, "innerHTML", {
            set: setInnerHTML
        });
    }
    return rv;
}
function setInnerHTML(html) {
    var index;

    for (index = 0; index < this.length; ++index) {
        this[index].innerHTML = html;
    }
}

// Usage
$("div").innerHTML = "The new HTML";
```

There, we use [`Object.defineProperty`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.6) to define a setter for the property.

In the comments below you say

> I have a few prototypes that work when individually attached to the $ function. Example: `$('div').makeClass('this');` They do not work when they are chained together. Example: `$('div').makeClass('this').takeClass('that');`

To make chaining work, you do `return this;` from each of the functions (so the end of `makeClass` would do `return this;`). That's because when you're chaining, such as `obj.foo().bar()`, you're calling `bar` on the return value of `foo`. So to make chaining work, you make sure `foo` returns `this` (the object on which `foo` was called).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I was only using innerHTML for demonstration purposes. I'm really curious to see if I can use the engine with other methods as well.

Comment: @o0110o: You're not using the selector engine for anything other than getting the list of matches. If you want to have further methods on your resulting objects, you have two options: Either assign them to each instance as you create it, or (and this is probably the better option) make your result objects not really arrays, but things you create with a prototype that has the additional features you want to add.

Comment: I have a few prototypes that work when individually attached to the $ function.
Example: $('div').makeClass('this');
They do not work when they are chained together.
Example: $('div').makeClass('this').takeClass('that');
This is why I want to push the results of each item returned into the method, if that's possible.

Comment: @o0110o - Here is a simple depiction using the `Array` method you demonstrated: http://jsfiddle.net/w52QH/ And on your last comment (after mine) you need to return the `object` from the methods you're chaining for it to access the original object.

Comment: @o0110o: To make chaining work, you do `return this` from each of the functions (so the end of `makeClass` would do `return this`).

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone. I'm going try this out and I'll post the results back here. Cheers!

Comment: @o0110o: I've folded the chaining stuff from the comments into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what works; it's a slightly different syntax then I gave in my prior example, but the end result is the same. I had some great help from other Stack Exchange members, thanks again everyone.

```
var $ = function(selector, node) { // Selector engine
    var selector = selector.trim(), node = node || document.body;
    if (selector != null) {
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(node.querySelectorAll(selector), 0); }
    }
}

if(!Array.prototype.html) { 
    Array.prototype.html = function(html) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            this[i].innerHTML = html;
        }
        return this; //<---- Silly me, my original code was missing this.
    }
}
```

When I run it, everything (including chaining) works as desired:

```
$("div").html('hello world');
```

OUTPUT:

```
<div>hello world</div>
```

Cheers!